# input element with css height: 100% overflow parent div

Tags: html, css

I try to create a search bar like Google's one. I wrote the following HTML:

```
<div id="settings-menu">
    <div class="search">
        <div class="search-icon"><i class="fi-xwluhl-magnifying-glass-wide"></i></div>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="settings-search">
            </div>
        <span class="clear interactive"><i class="fi-xwluxl-times-wide"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS for the input element:

```
#settings-menu input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
    color: var(--main-color);
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I don't understand why the input overflows the parents.
Here the full code in JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/ub4y7w8f/

Any help (and explanations) is welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your `box-sizing` is set to content box. Setting it to `border-box` will fix the sizing problem

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This is because by default, an input element has a vertical padding. Box sizing set to content-box adds the padding to the height value. This makes the total height of the element 100% + the padding leading to the overflow. You can read more about box-sizing [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

If you don't want to change the box sizing, you can rely on flexbox to align to align the content correctly:

```css
#settings-menu .search {
  align-items: center;
}
```

By aligning flex children to the center, the input will not overflow and will be positioned correctly

Comment: Quick, efficient and clean, everything I like. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Fifi my original response was wrong so I updated the answer